# PyQt4 how to restore a minimized window?

Tags: python, pyqt

**PyQt4 how to do if the window is minimized, call a method expand that window**

please tell me how to do it

I will be very grateful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the current state of a `QWidget` by calling its `windowState()` method. To change the state you pass a new state to `setWindowState()`.

Here's an example app that checks every 5 seconds to see if it's minimised. If it is then the window is restored.

This is just as an example - checking every 5 seconds for a minimised window and restoring it would be an evil thing to do in an app ;).

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt4.QtCore import QTimer, Qt

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(5000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.check_state)
        self.timer.start()

    def check_state(self):
        if self.windowState() == Qt.WindowMinimized:
            # Window is minimised. Restore it.
            self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowNoState)


if __name__ == '__main__':        
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks Gary, Thanks for the example but it took me a little easier :-)

Comment: Hi andrew, can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965872/pyqt-is-not-showing-button-if-i-set-window-to-showmaximize

Comment: Super helpful, thanks.  Lots of answers I've seen suggest `showMaximized()` which in my opinion is not the inverse of minimized.  `showMaximized()` restores the window to fill the screen whereas setting the window state to `WindowNoState` returns it to the prior view (at least on MacOS).

Answer (score 3):

The most accurate way to do this would be to watch for the `QWindowStateChangeEvent` of the widget, and respond immediately when it happens. You can do this more than one way.

Here is how you can re-implement the `event` method of the target widget:

```
class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

    def event(self, e):
        if e.type() == e.WindowStateChange:
            if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                print "Minimized"
                # self.showMaximized()

        # call the super class event() no matter what
        return super(Window, self).event(e)
```

Now if you have some other widget that you want to watch for Minimize, and you don't want to have to define a new event method on that object, you can create an object that simply watches events for multiple other objects. It is called an event filter:

```
class Watcher(QtCore.QObject):

    def eventFilter(self, obj, e):
        if obj.isWidgetType() and e.type() == e.WindowStateChange:
            if obj.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
                print "Minimized"
                # obj.showMaximized()

        return False


app = QtGui.QApplication([])

aWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
aWatcher = Watcher(aWindow)

aWindow.installEventFilter(aWatcher)

aWindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Note that when checking the `windowState`, you should use `&` to compare instead of `==`, because the state can be a combination of more than one value and you need to check it with a mask to see if the value is present amongst the others. i.e. if you maximize the window first and then minimize it, it will have multiple window states.

On a side note, you also have the option of customizing the actual window properties in the first place. So if your goal is to prevent minimizing, you could disable the button for it:

```
aWindow = QtGui.QWidget()
flags = aWindow.windowFlags()
aWindow.setWindowFlags(flags ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)
```

This will subtract the minimize button flag from all the other flags.

Answer (score 3):

**Hi guys me better come this way:**

```
if self.windowState() == QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:
   # Window is minimised. Restore it.
   self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
```

certainly not always this function is `working
probably the problem in the python
**thanks to all**

Comment: `if self.windowState() & QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized:` is better as it just checks for the minimized flag regardless of other flags.