# PyQt is not showing Button if i set window to showMaximize()

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

PyQt is not showing Button if i set window to showMaximize()

If i set a  self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
then the Button is showing perfectly Facing issue at showMaximized()

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        btn.resize(100, 100)
        btn.move(100, 100)
        self.show()


def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


run()
```

Any Help Would be appreciated ,

I need to place the Button at center of my Window .

Comment: Do not public the same question from your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966004/i-try-to-maximized-the-window-i-cant-visible-labels-button-in-pyqt

Comment: Sorry for it brother both of us try to learn Qt we are learning it by our self so we are stuck at some points.Can you please help ? just one more time ?

Comment: I already published an answer, review it and let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the children are shown by the parents, in your case when the parent is shown the button is not yet a child so it will not be shown, so there are 2 possible solutions:

1. Set as a child before `showMaximized()`

   ---

   ```
   class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self):
           super(Window, self).__init__()
           self.home()
           self.showMaximized()
           self.setWindowTitle("PyQT tuts!")
           self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('pythonlogo.png'))
   ```
2. call the show method of the button.

   ---

   ```
   def home(self):
       btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
       btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
       btn.resize(100, 100)
       btn.move(100, 100)
       btn.show()
   ```

Comment: When we apply it to our actual code its shows error 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'home'

Comment: here is the actual code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52966004/i-try-to-maximized-the-window-i-cant-visible-labels-button-in-pyqt

Comment: Thanks for Your Rply and undestand our situation

Comment: @abhikrishnan I have used the code you show in this question, the other question has too much code so I did not answer it (a lot of code is a way of bawling help).

Comment: @abhikrishnan Does my current answer answer your current question ?, I have not answered another question so if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: Defently. i will do it.

Comment: How to set it in a QtGui.QDialog instead of a QtMain.window

Comment: @abhikrishnan use the second method, in your code of the other question you have not created the home method.

Comment: Ok Brother Thanks now it's working fine in my actual code too. ThankYou very much for your patients