# New window appears upon calling minimized window (PyQt5)

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am using the PyQt5 python module to make a main window and a small window. When the user calls the window 2 from the window 1, and it is minimized (not closed), and tries to call it again from the window 1, another window appears.

I want instead to call the first minimized window to be maximized as normal. How can I check whether the window 2 is open or not?

```
def openwindow2(self):
    self.window2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.ui = Ui_window2()
    self.ui.setupUi(self.window2)
    #self.window2.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
    self.window2.show()
```

Comment: Can you show some of your code? Your bug could be from a multitude of reasons.

Comment: Thanks to those who helped me to edit the post, and sorry for my poor English, I also made some improvements to the post and also added some code for that

Answer (score 2):

What I can think of is a Boolean and setting it to true upon opening the new window:

```
def openwindow2(self):
 self.window2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
 --> alive = true
 self.ui = Ui_window2()
 self.ui.setupUi(self.window2)
 #self.window2.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
 self.window2.show()

def check_winodw_status:
 if alive = true:
    call_window
 else:
    openwindow2
```

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424557/pyqt4-how-to-restore-a-minimized-window) for more info on how to restore minimized windows.